# intel graphics keybinding conflict with other programs

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intel-graphics, key-binding

Intel HD graphics bindings take priority over bindings in other programs. When you disable them via the Intel HD graphics control panel, the bindings no longer function as mapped, but they are still grabbed by Intel HD graphics and thus do not work in other programs.

**Example:**
By default, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left-arrow</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right-arrow</kbd> are used by Intel HD graphics to rotate the display by 90 degrees left or right respectively. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) binds these keybindings to back and forward navigation respectively. Even if you disable the bindings in Intel HD graphics control panel, you still can't use them in PyCharm.

**How do I make Intel HD graphics free the keybindings?**

Answer (score 5):

Your question prompted me to revisit this problem and here is something useful:

[How to disable "igfxHK Module" process from starting up with Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/796396/how-to-disable-igfxhk-module-process-from-starting-up-with-windows)

In essence, kill the process and prevent it from starting. I guess depending on what version of the Intel HD graphics control panel you have, this might also be relevant:

http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/hkcmd.exe.html

Comment: This is a bless, I'm adding this hoping google can index this along with Sublime Text for any desperate soul searching for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The following workaround worked for me:

Instead of disabling the keybindings in Intel HD graphics control panel, enable them and change them to something else. You can then disable them if you wish.

The new keybindings will still be grabbed by Intel HD graphics as before, but at least you'll free up the bindings most important for you.

Comment: Unfortunately takes only special hotkeys starting with 1 or 2 Ctrl/Shift/Alts following by an alphanumeric char. I did not bother checking which is okay for me if overriden. (I use Intellij with tons of hotkeys :D) Although for a general user this workaround can be a solution. :)