# Windows cannot find igfxEm.exe or igfxTray.exe

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm experiencing these two errors notifications above when I reboot my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series). If I click OK, they disappear. What's causing this? The screenshots are as follow:

- igfxEM.exe

[image: igfxEM.exe]

- igfxTray.exe

[image: igfxTray.exe]

I've read this superuser answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/796396/how-to-disable-igfxhk-module-process-from-starting-up-with-windows), but it didn't solve my problem. As I'd like to get to the root of this with your help.

A few other key points that are related to this error:

1. If I try to open the 'View local services' on windows, I'm greeted with this message (never had this message before, only the past week - I only access services when I'm turning on/off the print spooler - currently running).

The program name: `mmc.exe` would like to make changes, I agree - it opens the services windows as normal. Why am I seeing this though? Program location is in `system32/mmc.exe`.

2. I'm now not able to print any PDF files in Chrome or Adobe Acrobat.

I've updated Intel drivers, ran Dell diagnostics and nothing has solved this for me yet. Here is the printer error in Chrome:

[image: print settings chrome]

In the past week I've deleted all my temp files and such. (Ran disk cleanup)

Any help or pointing me in right direction would be great.

Comment: *I've read this answer (...) but didn't solve my problem* That question has several answers. Which ones have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Possible way: 1. Remove the registry of those startup programs. 2. Uninstall and then reinstall the Intel Display driver.

Comment: @MichaelBay they work in the sense that when I disable the module - notification dissapears but I wan't to run it. I guess this is the root of the problem and the bigger picture is, windows is asking for permission to open up my 'services' control panel, which was never the case for me.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks for the input I will try. I'm just concerned I might mess up my driver completly once I delete the display driver

Comment: @Biswapriyo quick update. Started my laptop up this morning to a continuous restarting loop that has 0x00000098 or some random number. The screen flicked off too fast. Finally went into recovery and I had to delete all my applications. Errors are now gone but starting from a fresh windows 8.1